# How to click on a button that is located on the toolbar?

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, barista

I have a test in which I need to click on the button located on the toolbar. This button does not have an ID, but it has the name of the class - ImageButton. How can I click on it using Espresso or Barista? 
I can not do this because I do not have id

```
onView(...).perform(click());
```

Trying to use Baristo, but this does not work:

```
click(withClassName(ImageButton.class));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an id and use a robot class and invoke the method from uitest

```
fun clicksToolbarButton(): ActivityRobot {
    onView(withId(R.id.toolbar_button))
            .perform(scrollTo(), click())

    return this
  }
```

Comment: They said it doesn't have an ID